# Android ArrayAdapter for ListView method .notifyDataSetChanged() issue

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

I am trying to update `ListView` after another activity `finish()`'es with result. Initialization (works correctly):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    objects = databaseHelper.selectObjects();

    objectsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LIST_VIEW_OBJECTS);

    objectArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);

    objectsListView.setAdapter(objectArrayAdapter);
}
```

Problem occurs only when Im trying update `ListView`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            objects = databaseHelper.selectObjects();

            objectArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.TOAST_ERROR_RESULT_CANCELED), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

But this code works just fine:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            objects.add(newObject);

            objectArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.TOAST_ERROR_RESULT_CANCELED), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This code also works fine:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            objects = databaseHelper.selectObjects();

            objectArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);

            objectsListView.setAdapter(objectArrayAdapter);
        }

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.TOAST_ERROR_RESULT_CANCELED), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: why first method doesn't work as expected? Second and third seems to be a work round isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>In your first example, you are giving the information to questionnaires variable, which I don't see being related to your listview. onNotifyDataSetChanged() has the same data as before from what I can tell.</strike>

The second one works because you are directly changing the objects variable which is connected to your adapter.

EDIT:
"For an ArrayAdapter, notifyDataSetChanged only works if you use the add(), insert(), remove(), and clear() on the Adapter."
[notifyDataSetChanged example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example)

Comment: I am really sorry! I was trying to simplify my code for this question. `questionnaires` = `objects`. `ArrayList`'s in both examples are the same (now updated). Sorry again...

Comment: Oh okay, I'm not sure but I think obectsListView itself needs to be manipulated before calling onNotifyDataSetChanged. ex: objectsListView.clear,.add etc.

Comment: Hmmm... I really don't think so, because I have done similar functionality successfully before. The difference was that I added data to array like this: `objects.add(newObject);`. Here `objectsListView` is not manipulated too, isn't it?

Comment: I think the adapter is still holding a reference to the old values. This should clear things up.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example

Comment: But if I say `objectArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` shouldn't this method refresh all list with new data set?

Comment: The adapter references 'objects' the first time you created it. 
I believe the adapter now no longer looks at objects. 

It is like saying: 
    x = 10;
    y = x;
    x = 11;

y will still be 10, if that makes sense.
I could also be wrong, I'm not an expert on adapters.

The reason the second method works is because you force the adapter to reacquire the reference every time.